# Plotting bar plots with R

Tags: r

Am trying to create an R dodged geom bar with this data but am not getting a plot that i need

```
  Department              Male Female
  <chr>                  <int>  <int>
1 "Admin Offices"            3      6
2 "Executive Office"         0      1
3 "IT/IS"                   28     22
4 "Production       "       83    126
5 "Sales"                   16     15
6 "Software Engineering"     5      6
```

What i tried seems pretty wrong so anyone can help

Comment: Can you further explain what a dodged geom bar is? Better even if you could include an exemplary output, how your final plot should look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can only guess what you need actually. However The result could be this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)    
df<-data.frame(Department = c("Admin Offices", 
                              "Executive Office" ,    
                              "IT/IS",                
                              "Production",           
                              "Sales",                
                              "Software Engineering" ),
               Male = c(3, 0, 28, 83, 16, 5),
               Female = c(6, 1, 22, 126, 15, 6))

df %>% pivot_longer(cols = c("Male", "Female")) %>% 
  transmute(Department, Gender = as.factor(name), Value = value) %>% 
  ggplot() + 
  geom_bar(aes(x = Department, y = Value, fill = Gender), stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(0.9))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

And the same with `barplot` from base R:

```
df<-data.frame(Department = c("Admin Offices", 
                              "Executive Office" ,    
                              "IT/IS",                
                              "Production",           
                              "Sales",                
                              "Software Engineering" ),
               Male = c(3, 0, 28, 83, 16, 5),
               Female = c(6, 1, 22, 126, 15, 6))
barplot(t(df[,-1]), beside=T,
        names.arg=df$Department,
        legend.text=names(df[,-1]))
```

[image]